# How to do whitelist IPs on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, amazon-waf

I use the service of a third party "Website firewall: [Sucuri](https://sucuri.net/)". After creating an instance on AWS and updating the A record of IP of sucuri, it gives me an error `HTTP 502 - Unable to connect to the origin of server`. (side note: I am using the AWS service route53 to manage the DNS). When I have contacted the sucuri team, they gave me a list of IPs that should be whitelisted on the server.

Could you suggest to me how to put those IPs in whitelist on AWS?

Answer (score 0):

"whitelist on AWS" is too vague, you need to reword so that we know which layer of your architecture you want to whitelist, but it will not be r53, the whitelists can be set in AWS WAF with a WebACL,  ii r you have a public instance will be your Security Groups, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html

If deploying inside a VPC, the Network ACLs can be set as well.

you can do it via aws console with:
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress \
    --group-id $sgId  --protocol tcp --port 22 --cidr $Ipwhitelist

Answer (score 0):

```
You Need to Whitelist Sucuri IPs from your Web Server which you have created.
```

Go to the AWS Management Console and sign in to your account.

Click the Services menu and select EC2.
In the left navigation pane, click Security Groups

Click the Inbound Rules tap

Click the Edit inbound rules button
In the Add rule dialog box, select Custom from the Source drop-down menu

Enter the IP address or range of IP addresses that you want to whitelist in the Source text box

Select the Allow option from the Type drop-down menu
Click the Save button

```
I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any other questions.
```